# how to set the height of background image

Tags: css, html, background-image

I have an image.I wish to set it as background image.I want to it to cover the entire size so i used **background-size:cover;**.It covers the entire length but the image is clipped at the bottom.Can anyone help me to set the **background-size:cover;** also the image to its full length and height?

Answer (score 0):

Css have min height .. you can use it when your background size is cover...

Css:

```
.bg{
    background: url('path/to/image.png');
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="bg"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the vh CSS values (relative to viewport height): this will set the height to 1/10th of the height of the viewport:

```
    background-image:url('*YOUR URL HERE*');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    min-height:10vh;
```